# How to apply class to selected inline elements in Jade?

Tags: html, pug

in Jade:

```
section
  .line
    .red-words RED
    | TEXT
```

This would cause TEXT to be on another line to RED

I want to keep RED and TEXT inline, but only apply .red-words class to RED

Comment: Why not make them two separate spans? Like `span.red-words RED [enter] span TEXT`?

Comment: @Harry Is there another way other than using the Span tag?

Comment: I don't know Jade all that much but the other way might probably to handle them using CSS (set as inline). What is the output HTML that you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Add **span.**

```
section
  .line
    span.red-words RED
    | TEXT
```

or in CSS:

```
.red-words{display:inline;}
```